# Redis Cache Static List search by filter

Tags: c#, linq, redis, json.net, booksleeve

I have a static Object List about 500 items.

> This Object has property like (id [int],Name [string], attribute1
>   [string], attribute2 [string]).
>
> I have serialized this object into string and stored into redis as a
>   string key value. But I need to filter this list of 500 items based on
>   different user search filters fro object attributes and give subset of
>   this list to user.

I could do it in two ways one is add this list to a table and index and apply search filter using sql. Other is i pull this list from redis each time and de-serialize into
list of object and apply the filter using linq. i have redis on a different server so is DB , and i do not want to have a copy of that cache on the each web server as well.

> So, what is the best way to do it for a best performance? or is there
>   a different way to do it more faster?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the two approaches you had listed (using SQL or deserializing and filtering in the client) I'd like to suggest a slightly different one that is essentially a Redis index.

The idea is very simple: assuming your objects' key names are obj1, obj2...objn and that attribute1's values are val1, val2...valm, for each value x of attribute1 create a Redis set with a key name like `attribute1:valx:index`. The members of the set will be key names of objects that have their attribute1=valx. To make this happen, make sure that:

- When you create an objy with attribute1 value of valx, add `objy` to the `attribute1:valx:index` key.
- When you update attribute1 of objy from valx to valz, remove `objy` from `attribute1:valx:index` and add it to `attribute1:valz:index`.
- When you delete objy with attribute1=valx, remove `objy` from `attribute1:valx:index`.
- Optionally, the above should happen atomically (i.e. with Lua or a WATCH/MULTI/EXEC block), if that's important to your app.

These points are what's needed to maintain the index. Using the index is done by fetching the members (e.g. SMEMBERS) of the `attribute1:valx:index` set when looking for objects with filtered by attribute1=valx, and then fetching the actual objects via their key names (e.g. `objy`). Alternatively, using SORT .. GET (e.g. `SORT attribute1:valx:index GET obj*`) is another way to do that using just one command.

Repeat the same for attribute2. A couple of additional points:

- Look into using Redis' hashes to store your objects (e.g.  HSET objy attribute1 valx) to save on serialization overheads and easier manipulation of values in Redis.
- The simple index described above can be taken much further - consider using set operations such as SUNION, SDIFF & SINTER for more complex filtering options.